# How to select every row N times in MySql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table like below.

```
ID         NAME          SURNAME
1          Joe           Black
2          Mary          Peterson
3          Bob           Marley
4          Andy          Murray
...
```

I want to write a **SELECT** command which will return every row **N** times.
Example for N = 3.

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME  blah-blah (3 Times ) FROM Person
NAME              SURNAME
Joe               Black
Joe               Black
Joe               Black
Mary              Peterson
Mary              Peterson
Mary              Peterson
Bob               Marley
Bob               Marley
Bob               Marley
Andy              Murray
Andy              Murray
```

Thank you.

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a php loop)

Comment: i'll suggest to go with scripting language for this rather than sql (*if there is a way*)!!

Comment: That would be not a good idea , to create a multiple row when in fact you're retrieving actual data in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` to get the result you want, but you'd better not do such job with SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
) A ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The dumb manual way would be:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person
```

Another way is to have a table with numbers in a single column running up to the maximum and doing a cross join with it `WHERE number <= n`

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, clearly wasn't concentrating there

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest sql to achieve this, a much simpler way would be (*assuming PHP*) :

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT NAME, SURNAME  blah-blah (3 Times ) FROM Person");

while($result_set = $result->fetch_array())
{

   for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
   {
     echo $result_set['name']." ".$result_set['sur_name']."\n";
   }
}
```

This would give you a **better control on the result set** as well as, you can have more dynamic ways of handling, how the data is displayed on the page,

**for. eg**, if u want a particular name to be printed only once, a simple `if` comparison would do, which is not possible via sql!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM Person, (SELECT * FROM Person limit 3) count_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

what about go through looping it in stored procedure like that :

```
 delimiter //
 CREATE PROCEDURE ntimes()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
 SET i = 0;
 WHILE i < 3 DO   
 SELECT `Code`, `Rank`  FROM Table1;
 SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;
 END;
 //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Here you just change 3 to what number of repeats you want , and you dont need mass of unions .